# Regular expression ignore strings start with a specific string

Tags: regex

I need to find all the words containing some string. For example "team" and replace it with another string.
The string will as a substring for example:

1. team of experts
2. team manager
3. A big team

I need to replace all those places with the string `"hlhl$$@team"`.

I use the regular expression:

```
String exp= String.Format("({0}\\s)|({0}$)", "team);
```

The problem is that strings that are already are `"hlhl$$@team"` match the regular expression and are being replaced to `"hlhl$$@hlhl$$@team"`
How can I ignore those strings that start with `hlhl$$@`?
Thanks.

Comment: Look up negative lookbehind.

Comment: Is it C#? Try `Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<!hlhl\$\$@)\bteam\b", "hlhl$$$$@team")`

Answer (score 2):

[Negative Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is your friend.

You want `team` which is not preceded with `hlhl$$@`. So the regex is

```
(?<!hlhl\$\$@)team
```

Here `$` is required to escape because it is an special character in regex.